# How to convert hadoop sequence file to json format?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

As the name suggests, I'm looking for some tool which  will convert the existing data from hadoop sequence file to json format. 
My initial googling have only shown up results related to jaql, which I'm desperately trying to get to work.

Is there any tool from Apache available for this very purpose?

NOTE:
I've hadoop sequence file sitting on my local machine and would like to get data in corresponding json format.

So in-effect, I'm looking for some tool/utility which will take hadoop sequence file as input and produce output in json format.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought there must be some tool which will do this given that its such common requirement. Yes, it should be pretty easy to code but again why to do so if you already have something which does just the same. 
Anyway, I figured out to do it using jaql. Sample working query which worked for me,

read({type: 'hdfs', location: 'some_hdfs_file', inoptions: {converter: 'com.ibm.jaql.io.hadoop.converter.FromJsonTextConverter'}});

Answer (score 0):

Apache Hadoop might be a good tool for reading sequence files.

All kidding aside, though, why not write the simplest possible Mapper java program that uses, say, Jackson to serialize each key and value pair it sees?  That would be a pretty easy program to write.